# Scaling metarig model causes neck deformation

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, transforms, surface-deform

I am trying to scale my model in another file and when I do, the neck becomes skinny,tall and the shoulders are all weird when I scale the model. I've already tried clearing the transformations and applying transformations. Especially when it comes to scale, the whole mesh explodes when I apply it. This is very weird because it's all because of the metarig. if it was a normal armature, it wouldn't have an issue. FYI, the model I'm trying to scale is not a model I made, it's a model I downloaded of the internet. I'm trying to scale it alongside my other model. I've tried all the other ways I've found on this forum for similar issues but to no avail./[image]

In some way the scaling is right BUT-- when I move it up, it still has that issue with the shoulders and neck when I try moving it up beside my other model. I can see the shoulders shrinking when I move it up.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The simpler solution is to use the root bone in pose mode to scale and move the whole rig + character system.

If you really need to have the new scale applied, the procedure is to delete the rig, scale the model and the Metarig together in obj mode, apply the scale to both model and Metarig, then regenerate the rig. All weights will remain preserved.